# showing "No video with supported format and mime type found"

Tags: video, codeigniter-3

Tried a lot to get a solution from the problem but not,the issue am facing here is the video is uploading and storing in to the database but while viewing it showing like this `No video with supported format and mime type found`.
code looks like this

```
<video width="228" height="180" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/videos/170523a.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
  <source src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/videos/170523a.webm" type="video/webm"  />
</video>
```

In .htaccess file i included like this

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /zara/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

#Allow from 122.252.226.125
#Deny from all
```

want to get relief from this,please help me to get out from this

Comment: What version of the browser (I assume Firefox) are you using?

Comment: am using Firefox and already gave  in .htaccess

Comment: its not getting even in crome

Comment: Can you play the video on your computer? And can you check the links to see if the files are really there?

Comment: yaa i can play the video on computer and the files are really there

Comment: Check if your route is ok. `<div><?php var_dump(base_url() . "uploads/videos/170523a.webm";?></div>`. After copy your route and paste in your address bar of your browser, if the route is correct then you will get the video playing with native browser playback.

Comment: when i did like what u told am getting result as `No video with supported format and mime type found`